Do most women enjoy sex?
The YouTube video by clinical psychologist, Dr. Whiten (Dr. Psych Mom) called "women do enjoy sex... in depth discussion about why you may not think so" makes the claim that most women enjoy physical intimacy / sex.
This is apparent by the on screen caption and at 45 second and mentioned a couple of times throughout the video.

I interpret "most" as 51% or more.
Enjoy sex does not mean all the time no matter the circumstances it means when a reasonable set of circumstances arise.

There is also a link of the page to a description but it does not refer to research 6-reasons-you-think-women-dont-enjoy-sex.
The presenter has about 100K+ followers on Facebook.
Do most women enjoy sex?

I've deleted some comments that demanded a higher-than-required standard for the question. I invite people who think the answer is obvious to consider that there are some people who hold the opposite view, and this is a great opportunity to teach them with empirical evidence.

Yes, according to a 2004 ABC News survey 59% of women enjoy sex "a great deal" and an additional 25% of women enjoy sex “somewhat”.  5% responded that they enjoyed sex “not too much”, 7% enjoyed sex “not at all” and 2% had no opinion.  Though not one of the choices, 1% of women responded by saying they never had sex.

Note that this was a "random-sample telephone poll of 1,501 adults", so really it's a sample of people that have publicly listed phone numbers and like to talk about personal sexual matters to strangers on the telephone, not a representative sample of the general population.

@RayButterworth once informed of the subject matter of the survey, 92% still completed the survey.     https://abcnews.go.com/images/Politics/959a1AmericanSexSurvey.pdf

If people don't always enjoy sex (for example, a spouse is required on demand) they might shy away from a poll about sexual enjoyment. Polls are from people who respond, and are not an objective survey. A poll is not a controlled study. But biologically, people are designed to enjoy sex, so why should the statistic be a surprise?

@WeatherVane: Polls have flaws, but they are also can be a scientific measuring tool. We don't get to dismiss all poll results out of hand. It is unclear to me how we would work out if a population enjoyed sex without asking them. "people are designed to enjoy sex" is an unreferenced claim, and as skeptics, we should be willing to entertain that our intuitions are wrong, and to be asked to support our claims with empirical evidence.

It's hard to imagine how the question could in principle be answered other than by survey results. It's not as if "enjoyment" could be determined objectively (and reliably) by externally observable physical signs; and even if that were workable, a study on that basis would certainly not pass any ethics review boards.
